# Rendering Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, rendering

I'm a absolute beginner in programming but I'd love to create my own Apps to make my (and someone else's) everyday life a little easier. I just downloaded the latest version of Android Studio and installed it with all tools.

I wanted to create a "Hello World" App as shown in many tutorials on YouTube. I followed them step by step but there is always this **Rendering Problem** directly after I finished creating a blank activity.

> Rendering Problems
>
> The following classes could not be instantiated:
>        -android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
>
> Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE
>
> Exception Details
>   android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x1080029 at ....

I have no clue what the problem could be and how I solve it and all the answers on google and here on stackoverflow.com to a already existing **Rendering Problem** couldn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in the **Android Studio** and **Android Design Support Library** (ver 23.2.0) that is solved in Dev/Canary channel.

For now, if you use the Stable update channel, you have to edit by hand the build.gradle file.
Under **Project tool window** -> **Gradle Scripts** open and edit the file **build.gradle (Module: app)**.
Search for **dependencies** and make sure the **com.android.support.design** line looks like this:

> compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'

**Save**

**Tools** -> **Android** -> **Sync Project with Gradle Files**

**Build** -> **Rebuild**